# How to check to make sure that blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path() was successful in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have to make sure the data was uploaded. Is there a better way then this ? Specially i want to get some meta of the transaction?

```
try:
     blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(
     'user',
     fileName+'.'+ext,
     fileName+'.'+ext)

except:
     print sys.exc_info()[1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure SDK for python supports `progress_callback` method. We can monitor the progress using callback function.

*Callback for progress with signature `function(current, total)` where          `current` is the number of bytes transfered so far, and `total` is the            size of the blob, or None if the total size is unknown.*

```
def progress_callback(current, total):
    print current
    print "==============="
    print total
    print "==============="
    if(current<total):
        print "unfinish"
    else:
        print "finish"
blob_service = BlobService(account_name=storage_account_name, account_key=storage_account_key)
blob_service.put_block_blob_from_path(container, blob_name, 'C:\\Users\\file_path',progress_callback=progress_callback)
```

Also, you can use `Storage Explore Tool` or `list_blob` method to check files if you want to know whether is on Azure Storage.
Please try it.